# How to upload image on exoscale s3 bucket from react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to upload the image on exoscale s3 bucket from react
i am using aws-sdk library for that but it gave me error like

**PUT https://crm-staging.sos.ch-gva-2.exo.io/Screenshot%202023-07-24%20at%2011.33.23%20AM.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

This is piece of code which i try

```
  const handleImageUploadCallback = async (file, done) => {
    const bucketName = "crm-staging";
    const accessKeyId = process.env.REACT_APP_EXOSCALE_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
    const secretAccessKey = process.env.REACT_APP_EXOSCALE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
    const region = "ch-gva-2";

    AWS.config.update({
      region: region,
      credentials: new AWS.Credentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey),
      endpoint: `https://sos.${region}.exo.io`,
      s3: `https://sos.${region}.exo.io`,
    });

    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const param = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: file.accepted[0].name,
      Body: file.accepted[0],
      ContentType: "image/png",
    };
    s3.upload(param, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error uploading file:", err);
        alert("Failed to upload the file.");
      } else {
        console.log("File uploaded successfully:", data);
        alert("File uploaded successfully.");
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Could it be that your code does not work in a container environment?
Because your code looks good so far.